# Add referrer code to url

Tags: url-rewriting, wordpress

I need add the url of a wordpress blog a referrer code with this structure:

http://domain/([a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}/...

The site should work both with and without this code.
If there is I have to use it, store it in session type.

All through plugin so you do not have problems with upgrades or any wordpress plugin.

I also tried to edit the file .htaccess with a custom RewriteRule but nothing.

Ideas? Thanks!

Sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to install the plugin [Rewrite](http://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/) and create rules to manage the referrer.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel here, there plugins that gives you affiliate program features so you won't have to worry about url and links.
try some of this plugins: [Tag: referral](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/referral)

you can also try this one as it has a good description: [Affiliates](http://wordpress.org/plugins/affiliates/)

With wordpress always check existing plugins when you want to add functionality to your website, there are a lot of plugins that do a lot of things.

Edit: you can create your referal link as domain.com?ref=code and in the website header check for $_GET['ref'] if it exists save the ref in a session variable, if the user gets to register then take the ref value from the session variable. This should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had already looked at the wordpress plugins but none of them does what I need.

I need to have that code in session to use it during the registration of a new customer, in a custom e-commerce and insert it in the links of the site so as not to lose it if they had to share a few pages.

I have already outlined the plugin that will manage the other functions but this is driving me crazy.

The only solution that comes to mind is to replicate all of the rewrite rule present in wordpress.

Comment: @phpwriter : pls check edit, I think using session variables should work